# Si los registros relacionados tienen la misma fecha iterar juntos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo una linea de tiempo como si de un historial de movimientos se tratase, la cuestión es que un mismo día se pueden editar dos veces un mismo registro y ahí es donde se me complica el asunto porque no se como comparar para itererar de manera distinta.

**Mi tabla equipos**

| id | serie | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GNOEIRGNE | Equipo 1 |
| 130 | WEFWEFEW | Equipo 2 |

**Mi tabla historia equipos**

| id | admin_id | equipo_id | fecha_creado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 130 | 2021-09-29 |
| 2 | 1 | 130 | 2021-09-29 |

**Así hago la consulta para iterar los equipos**

```php
$equipos = Equipo::with('historiaEquipo')
    ->leftjoin('clientes AS cliN', 'equipos.cliente_id', '=', 'cliN.id')
    ->leftjoin('modelos', 'equipos.referencia', '=', 'modelos.id' )
    ->leftjoin('clientes AS clie', 'clie.id', '=', 'cliN.asociado_id')
    ->leftjoin('clientes AS clie2', 'clie2.id', '=', 'equipos.propietario')
    ->select(
        'equipos.*',
        'cliN.name AS nombreCliente',
        'cliN.apellidos',
        'cliN.empresa',
        'cliN.centro',
        'cliN.id AS idCliente',
        'cliN.asociado_id',
        'modelos.modelo AS refeEquipo',
        'modelos.foto',
        'clie.centro AS centroDistri',
        'clie2.centro AS centroPropietario'
    )
    ->orderBy('equipos.fecha_adquirido')
    ->get();
```

**Luego en la vista**

```xml
<!-- Iteramos los equipos -->
@foreach ($equipos as $eq) 
    <!-- Itero las historias realacionadas con este equipo -->
    @forelse ($eq->historiaEquipo as $historia)
    
    @empty
        <div class="alert alert-warning editalert" role="alert" style="font-size: 13px;">
            No tiene movimientos
        </div>
    @endforelse
@endforeach
```

**Luego lo que pongo dentro del `@forelse`**

```xml
<div class="timeline-section">
  <div class="timeline-date">
    {{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($historia->fecha_creado ))}}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="timeline-box">
        <div class="box-title">
          @php $miFoto =auth()->user()->foto; @endphp
          <img src="{{ asset("{$miFoto}") }}" alt="" class="imgHistoria">
          {{ $historia->administradorHistoria->name }} {{ $historia->administradorHistoria->apellidos }}
        </div>
        @if($loop->first)
          <div class="box-content">
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Acción</strong>: Dar de alta equipo
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Nª de serie</strong>: {{ $eq->serie }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Cliente</strong>: N/D
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Propietario</strong>: Empresa
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Estado</strong>: Almacén
            </div>
          </div>
        @else 
          <div class="box-content">
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Acción</strong>: Editar equipo
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Cliente</strong>: {{ $historia->clienteHistoria->name }} {{ $historia->clienteHistoria->apellidos }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Centro</strong>: {{ $historia->clienteHistoria->centro }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Empresa</strong>: {{ $historia->clienteHistoria->empresa }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Propietario</strong>: 
              @if ($historia->propietario == null)
              @else
                @if ($historia->propietario == 1)
                  <span>Distribuidor</span>
                @elseif ($historia->propietario == 2)
                  <span>Cliente final</span>
                @else
                  <span>{{ $historia->propietarioHistoria->centro }}</span>
                @endif 
              @endif
            </div>
            <div class="box-item">
              <strong>Estado</strong>: 
                @if ($historia->estado == 0)
                  <span>Almacén</span>
                @elseif ($historia->estado == 1)
                  <span>Alquiler</span>
                @elseif ($historia->estado == 2)
                  <span>Venta</span>
                @elseif ($historia->estado == 3)
                  <span>Opción a compra</span>
                @endif
              </div>
              <div class="box-item">
                <strong>Entregado</strong>: {{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($historia->fecha_adquirido )) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          @endif
          <div class="box-footer">
            <i class="fas fa-dot-circle"></i> Revisión correcta
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

La fecha que muestra en la vista:

```xml
<div class="timeline-date">
    {{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($historia->fecha_creado ))}}
</div>
```

Si son de la misma fecha la iteración tendría que hacerla dentro del `row` no repetir el `timeline-section` espero haberme explicado bien.

Pongo el modelo Equipo por si es necesario:

```php
public function historiaEquipo()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HistoriaEquipos::class, 'equipo_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el método `groupBy()` de `Collection` con un callback para agrupar por fecha justo en el formato que quieres.

```xml
@foreach ($equipos as $eq) 
  @forelse ($eq->historiaEquipo->groupBy(fn($historia) => date('d-M-Y', strtotime($historia->fecha_creado))) as $fecha => $historiaAgrupada)
    <div class="timeline-section">
      <div class="timeline-date">
        {{ $fecha }}
      </div>
      @foreach ($historiaAgrupada as $historia)
        <div class="row">
          ...
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  @empty
    <div class="alert alert-warning editalert" role="alert" style="font-size: 13px;">
      No tiene movimientos
    </div>
  @endforelse
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola @IGP al hacer el `forelse` con lo que me dices me devuelve este error: `syntax error, unexpected '=>'`

Comment: Estas con php > 7.4? Si no, reemplaza el `(fn($historia) => date(....))` por `(function ($historia) { return date(...); })`